# Disable save button after modification (in a console) in angular form

Tags: angularjs, forms

I have write a classical angular form with 4 areas : Language, Currency, Date format and Amount format.
Here is my full .html code :

```
<uib-tab index="1" heading="{{'GENERAL_SETTINGS_LABEL' | translate}}">
  <section class="general-settings">
    <div class="listing">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="language">{{'LANGUAGE_LABEL' | translate}}</label>
          <select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
          <option value="en">{{'referencedata.languages.EN' | translate}}</option>
          <option value="nl">{{'referencedata.languages.NL' | translate}}</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="currency">{{'CURRENCY_LABEL' | translate}}</label>
          <select id="currency" name="currency" ng-model="paramsGEN.cur.paramUserValue">
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
          <option value="USD">USD</option>
          <option value="GBP">GBP</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="date-format">{{'DATE_FORMAT_LABEL' | translate}}</label>
          <select id="date-format" name="date-format" ng-model="paramsGEN.date.paramUserValue">                              
          <option value="dd/MM/yyyy">dd/MM/yyyy</option>
          <option value="dd-MM-yyyy">dd-MM-yyyy</option>
          <option value="MM/dd/yyyy">MM/dd/yyyy</option>
          <option value="yyyy-MM-dd">yyyy-MM-dd</option>
          <option value="MM-dd-yyyy">MM-dd-yyyy</option>
          <option value="yyyy/MM/dd">yyyy/MM/dd</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="amount-format">{{'AMOUNT_FORMAT_LABEL' | translate}}</label>
          <select id="amount-format" name="amount-format" ng-model="paramsGEN.amt.paramUserValue">
          <option value="1 234 567,89">1 234 567,89</option>
          <option value="1 234 567.89">1 234 567.89</option>
          <option value="1.234.567,89">1.234.567,89</option>
          <option value="1,234,567.89">1,234,567.89</option>
          </select>
          </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section class="controls">
          <div class="controls-wrapper">
            <button type="button" ng-click="saveGeneralParams();" class="apply bt">{{'APPLY_LABEL' | translate}}</button>
            </div>
        </section>
    </uib-tab>
```

What I want to do is that if the user opens the console (F12 button and inspect elements) and wants to change the value of an area for example 'Language' **with another value that is not in the list**. For example, he opens the console and change this line :

```
 <option value="sp">  <!--he puts "sp" rather than the initial "en"-->
```

Then, if he wants to save by clicking the save button, I have to **disable** this button. And I want to that for the other areas.

I have no idea how can I do that. Is it possible to add a check for the initial value in this html file or do I have to add a special function for that in my controller???

Thank you in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your-own function to check the value set on each ng-model, then use that function to disable the submit button (ng-disabled).

Something like

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.validate = function() {
        if($scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue === 'en' || $scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue === 'nl') {
           return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}]);
```

Then in your button in html

```
<button type="button" ng-click="saveGeneralParams();" class="apply bt" ng-disabled="validate()">{{'APPLY_LABEL' | translate}}</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure for that please ??? I wrote exactly what you said but it didn't work for me. The page still refresh if I put another value (like "fr" or "es") in the option tag....I'm not sure but I think that ng disabled is not sufficient in that case because I want to block the fresh in that case....

Comment: is it possible to include a code to block the redirection to other undesirable pages? For example, if the user choose english as language, he will be redirect to settings/en/ which is correct but if he changes (in the console) the option tag with "sp" or "fr", he will be redirect to settings/fr/ or settings/sp/ and I want to block that redirection. Is it possible????

Comment: If the validation fails, it wont submit the form. ie if the redirection function call is put in ng-click of submit button or ng-submit to the form, those functions will not get called if the button is disabled.

Comment: I had updated the answer as i forgot to inject $scope to the controller. Please check whether any JavaScript error in your code, the page may redirect if there is any js error.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do is that if the user opens the console (F12 button
>   and inspect elements) and wants to change the value of an area for
>   example 'Language' with another value that is not in the list. For
>   example, he opens the console and change this line :
>
> Then, if he wants to save by clicking the save button, I have to
>   disable this button. And I want to that for the other areas.

Javascript is client-side. From client-side, you could never be sure to prevent a smart or malicious user to disable some controls, modify some objects or send to server a request with data you consider as unacceptable.
Some Javascript lib and practices may make harder malicious user behaviors but it would be always limited.

The single real protection comes from server-side. If you deem that some processing must be secured (here valid values), you should do the check in the server-side.

---

**update : asked solution in comment**

The idea is playing with `ng-disabled` attribute of button that you map to a variable in `$scope controller`.
If the submitted language is acceptable, no problem, otherwise, we leave the processing and we disable the button via the variable in `$scope controller`.

So, add `ng-disabled` attribute in the button:

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="button" 
         ng-click="saveGeneralParams();" class="apply bt" ></button>
```

And add at the beginning of `saveGeneralParams()`  :

```
 $scope.saveGeneralParams = function() {
      if($scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue != 'en' && $scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue != 'nl') {
          $scope.isDisabled = true;
          return;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript (i'm a beginner) and I agree about that point. But in that example, the save button send the user to another page like settings/en/ if the chosen language is english or settings/nl if it is deutch. What I want to do technically is to block the other redirections to other pages like settings/sp or settings/fr (for spanish, french...) after clicking on the save button. I don't know if it was clear for you but i think that is technically possible in angular no?

Comment: I didn't know that the form went to a setting page but in this case, it is still better since integrity data of your system is respected. Why bothering with malicious user which would see a page with missing data if the that user hacks your client side form ?
If your settings page is accessible from another way (url for example), nothing prevent the user to access it ?
Anyway, I can show you the idea to implement your need

Comment: Can you show me please how can I block the redirection to undesirable pages? like settings/fr/ or settings/en rather than availables pages (like settings/en and settings/nl)  Please. Thanks !

Comment: I updated with a simple workaround. It doesn't handle re-enabling button if suitable value is selected since it is a malicious usage. You may easily handle that case if you wish.

Comment: It doesn't work, I'm still having a refresh if I change the values... I think ng-disabled is not sufficient, do I have to use something like $dirty ??

Comment: "It doesn't work, I'm still having a refresh if I change the values... " Re-read my update : the workaround is not based on disable when  refreshing value but when clicking button .